# Log actions with NHibernate in database

Tags: c#, .net, nhibernate, autofac

I need a solution for logging and save the database user actions in the system, I need to record the User, the entity, the previous state and the current state of the entity and the date that the user made the change. I am using NHibernate,Autofac and .net 4.0 c#. I thought of creating an attribute filter and put in methods that need to generate the log, but also have interceptors that were created with the Autofac, but still can not think of the best solution, I really need help because they still have not implemented anything like

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use some `Listeners` in Nhibernate. It works like triggers in database but in the ORM level. For sample, on `PreUpdate` method, you could take the old state and the new state of the object the ORM are changing and track some log. If you have a user logged on your AppDomain, you could take this information from the `IPrincipal` object. You have to inherit from the interfaces like `IPreUpdateEventListener` and `IPreInsertEventListener` and implement some method of these interfaces in a class. After it, configure your `SessionFactory` to use these listeners. There a lot of listerners you can see here.

Look these links:

http://darrell.mozingo.net/2009/08/31/auditing-with-nhibernate-listeners/

http://ayende.com/blog/3987/nhibernate-ipreupdateeventlistener-ipreinserteventlistener

http://nhibernate.info/doc/howto/various/creating-an-audit-log-using-nhibernate-events.html

PS: When you set a listener, it will work for every entity, do not forget to check the type you want to add this behaviour.

Answer (score 2):

To audit database changes I can recommend NHibernate.Envers. I've used it in a previous project with good results.

[NHibernate.Envers](https://bitbucket.org/RogerKratz/nhibernate.envers)